# Google Analytics - Goal Funnel Setup with Dynamic Urls

Tags: google-analytics

I've setup an goal funnel with dynamic urls in Google Analytics, but I am not sure if I did it correclty.

Funnel Steps:

1. Home Page, `^/`
2. Pick First, `^/compare`
3. Pick Second, `^/compare/([^/]+)/`
4. Compare, `^/compare/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/`

The goal-URL is (regex) `^/go/.*` which is a redirect link, for e.g. `www.domain.com/go/comparedcompany`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tested it out and did you see any conversion, either in you standard reports or in real time?

Comment: Yes, I ran some tests but there are no conversions at all. Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually reconfigure your regexes as follows:

Step 1: `^\/$`

Step 2: `^\/compare$`

Step 3: `^\/compare\/.*\/$`

Step 4: `^\/compare\/.*\/.*\/$`

Goal: `^\/go\/.*`

(Also, as a note, using GA's regex engine, you don't need to escape your slashes, but I normally do it anyway.)

The reason why I went with `.*` instead of `[^/]+` is because you probably won't get a page like `/compare//` (if you do, then you have other things to worry about :-P).